# Is grails repo down?

Tags: grails

Today no matter what we do can't download anything from https://repo.grails.org/grails/core.

Visting the url in browser returns **404** too.

Is there a new repo url? I have checked the [Grails code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/d2a24c8af355b682a7fd0a3309651c311bc85ae2/grails-shell/src/main/groovy/org/grails/cli/boot/GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy) for some updates but the repo url is all the same.

**Update**

It seems like a temporary outage only. Everything started to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's back now, looks like it was just an intermittent outage.